# Locked / unmovable vertices in part of a Combined Mesh

Tags: modeling, vertices

I created a humanoid but, after merging the parts together, I can't seem to move the hand vertices in any way in vertex mode. I can't even select them. It's all one Mesh without any modifiers exept for an armature modifier.
Here Is a video Showing the problem: https://youtu.be/ySUpQvKpPbE

Comment: I believe that's a bug that may happen to anyone, could you possibly try copying/appending the file to older (not 2.9) version and unhide the vertices on edit mode?

Comment: maybe try to unhide, I think someone had a similar problem few days ago, and it seems to be a bug

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to moonboots I found out that it can be solved by entering edit mode and then unhiding everything.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114187)

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 I don't know how to accept a comment on the original question as answer.

Comment: You can also simply mark your own answer as the correct answer (since it is an *answer*), just next time try to not simply post "Thank you" as a large part of your answer.