# Can't edit vertices on hand

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, visibility

I'm trying to scale up the hands but the vertices aren't selectable. The hands were made separately, but it's all in one object now with an armature and all that. All the other vertices are editable.

[image]

Comment: It appears that the hand is either another object or part of a modifier with the mesh. Could you post the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to your post? It would help a lot!

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 just did, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

The vertices were just hidden. I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202768/locked-unmovable-vertices-in-part-of-a-combined-mesh) which worked.

process for other newbies:

1. Select the object
2. Enter edit mode
3. Select all with 'A' key
4. Show hidden using 'Option' + 'H' key